implementing the SIRD model in python
im doing a project for my class where im trying to implement the sird model with the vaccinated population. Ive written my code based on the equations i have but something seems off in my graph. the vaccinated population doesnt really increase at all, and the recovered and deceased population become almost constant around the 80 day mark. I dont know if the graph is supposed to turn out that way or not. can someone help me fix my code? im not using odeint btw


import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#sirdv
#a-alpha b-beta g-gamma d-detla m-mu e=vaccine efficacy
#N=population s(t)=susceptible d(t)=deceased i(t)=infected r(t)=recovered v(t)=vaccinated
#n=s+i+r+d+v
# ds/dt=-b/N(si) dr/dt=gi dd/dt=mi di/dt=b/N(si-gi-mi)-a*s) dv/dt=a*s-(e*b*i*v)/N
N=1000 #total population
b=0.5 # transmission rate ranged from 0.4 to 0.6
a=0.05 #5 % of susceptible population
e=0.7 #as of now 
g=1/7 # recovery rate
m=0.01 #death rate between 0.01 to 0.1 %
M=(m)/(m+g) #=fatalities/resolutions
R0=b/g
print(M)
print(R0)

steps=np.arange(0,365,dtype=int)
time=1*steps
def SIRDV(s,i,r,d,b,g,m,a,v,e):
    sdash= -s*i*(b/(s+i+r+d+v))-(a*s)
    rdash=g*i
    idash=((s*i*b)/(s+i+r+d+v))-(g*i)-(m*i)
    ddash=m*i
    vdash=(a*s)-((e*b*i*v)/(s+i+r+d+v))

    return sdash, idash, rdash, ddash, vdash

tlen=len(time)
s=np.empty([tlen])
i=np.empty([tlen])
r=np.empty([tlen])
d=np.empty([tlen])
v=np.empty([tlen])


r[0]=0
i[0]=1
d[0]=0
v[0]=0
s[0]=N-i[0]-r[0]-d[0]-v[0]

dt=0.05

for t in steps:
    if t<len(steps)-1:
        sdash, idash, rdash, ddash, vdash= SIRDV(s[t],i[t],r[t],d[t],v[t],b,g,m,e,a)
        s[t+1]=s[t]+dt*sdash
        i[t+1]=i[t]+dt*idash
        r[t+1]=r[t]+dt*rdash
        d[t+1]=d[t]+dt*ddash
        v[t+1]=v[t]+dt*vdash


plt.plot(time,s,label='susceptible')
plt.plot(time,i,label='infected')
plt.plot(time,r,label='recovered')
plt.plot(time,d,label='deceased')
plt.plot(time,v,label='vaccinated')
plt.xlabel('time in days')
plt.ylabel('no of people')
plt.legend()
plt.pause(0.01)
plt.show()

my code is pretty simple so idk whats wrong :/

This is a good example of why meaningful variable names are better than single letters, even though it's more typing. E.g. use death_rate instead of m.

@gabagool And that is why functions in Python libraries often have named arguments instead of positional ones )

An order of arguments in your function SIRDV is not same as when you calling this function:
def SIRDV(s,i,r,d,b,g,m,a,v,e):
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^
...
SIRDV(s[t],i[t],r[t],d[t],v[t],b,g,m,e,a)
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Аfter changing function signature in corresponding order:
def SIRDV(s,i,r,d,v,b,g,m,e,a):

I'v got such picture, which is more meaningful, I hope.

And I recommend you to draw one more picture without two lines with big numbers which keep rest of lines too low to see them.
plt.figure()
#plt.plot(time,s,label='susceptible')
plt.plot(time,i,label='infected', color='orange')
plt.plot(time,r,label='recovered', color='green')
plt.plot(time,d,label='deceased', color='red')
#plt.plot(time,v,label='vaccinated')
plt.xlabel('time in days')
plt.ylabel('no of people')
plt.legend()



thank u sm!! the graph you got is what i was looking for. thank uuu
